# Pass ClientMetaData or ValidationData to Lambda Trigger while calling FederatedSignIn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

During Google Sign in AWS Cognito using `federatedSignIn` I wanted to pass some custom data using `clientMetaData` or `validationData` to Pre Authentication Trigger Lambda. Is it possible ?

Here is the code for Google sign using `federatedSignIn`

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({provider : CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google})
```

Any help would be appreciated ?